# In Magnolia, how does one hide a specific element in the administration section?

Tags: magnolia

I have an element that is obstructing the "Edit component" button (because of some CSS) in the page edition.

Is there a way to hide a specific element only for the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[#if !cmsfn.isEditMode()]` did the trick